# Using tr to change many files names

Tags: tr

I am basically trying to replace all special characters in directory names and files names with a period. I am attempting to use tr, but I am very new and I do not want to mess up all of my music naming and picture naming. I am making the switch from windows to linux and trying to get everything in a nice formatted pattern. I have used tr semi successfully but I would like some pro help from you guys! Thanks in advance! I have looked at the tr man pages but I am just worried about really messing up 12 years of pictures and music file names! The two man characters I am trying to replace are " - " but the naming scheme I've used in windows has been by hand over the years and it varies, so I was hoping to go through everything and replace all cases of "-" or " - " manly but any fat fingering I have done over the years and put in something besides that patter would be great. I am thinking something like:

tr -cd [:alnum:] '.'

would this work?

My main goal is to turn something like

01 - Name Of Song (or any variation of special/punctuation characters)

into

01.Name.Of.Song

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want to use the `d` option since it just deletes the matched characters. And you may want to use the `s` (squeeze) option. Try this:

```
tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '.'
```

You can test it like this:

```
echo '01 - Name Of Song' | tr -cs '[:alnum:]' '.'
```

(Ignore the extra period at the end of the output. That's just the newline character and won't appear in filenames ... generally.)

But this is probably not of much use in your task. If you want to do a mass rename, you might use a little perl program like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

$START_DIRECTORY = "Music";
$RENAME_DIRECTORIES = 1;   # boolean (0 or 1)

sub procdir {
  chdir $_[0];
  my @files = <*>;
  for my $file (@files) {
    procdir($file) if (-d $file);
    next if !$RENAME_DIRECTORIES;
    my $oldname = $file;
    if ($file =~ s/[^[:alnum:].]+/\./g) {
      print "$oldname => $file\n";
#      rename $oldname, $file; # may not rename directories(?)
    }
  }
  chdir "..";
}

procdir($START_DIRECTORY);
```

Run it with the `rename` command commented out (as above) to test it. Uncomment the `rename` command to actually rename the files. Caveat emptor. There be dragons. Etc.

Comment: Very cool, my filing system is setup like this Music->Artist Folders-> Track Titles. I tried the above command and it won't work, it tries and just gets stuck without doing any thing is there a recursive way to start at the Music directory and change all artist folder names and the go in and change all the title names? I've seen a few ways to do it but as it said before I do not want to try without advice before I do try!

Comment: I spoke incorrectly it will once in the artist folder and I'm using it on files but I am trying to start from the top and have it go through about 100 artist folders and renaming those and then go into the artist folders and rename the track filenames.

Comment: @user3347022 Maybe `tr` is not what you're looking for. See the edit to my answer above.

Comment: Wow worked great! Worked for all my pictures as well just the way I wanted them to turn out! Thank you for all your help, you saved a few weeks of hand doing every rename! Thanks!